# Understanding instance and class variable python

Tags: python

Let's suppose I have 2 classes in different scenario.

**Scenario 1**

```
class MyClass():
    temp = 5
```

**Scenario 2**

```
class MyClass():
    temp = 5

    def myfunc(self):
          print self.temp
```

Now when will variable `temp` will be treated as a class variable and instance variable. I am confused because in both the scenarios I am able to access the value of variable `temp` using both.

1. `Object.Temp` (behaving as instance variable)
2. `ClassName.Temp` (behaving as class variable)

I believe similar questions have been asked before but it will be a great help if someone can explain this in context of my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class variables are shared between all instances of a class. With immutable types (like int, str, ...) you won't note much of a difference. But consider this:

```
class MyClass():
    temp = []  
    def myfunc(self, val):
          self.temp.append(val)
          print self.temp

instance1 = MyClass()
instance1.myfunc(1)    # [1]
instance2 = MyClass()
instance2.myfunc(2)    # [1, 2]
```

In this case both instances share the *same* list, that is if the instance doesn't have a `temp` member itself, then that of the class is used.

So if you further do:

```
MyClass.temp.append(3)
print instance1.temp   # [1, 2, 3]
instance1.temp = []
print instance1.temp   # []         uses the instances temp
print instance2.temp   # [1, 2, 3]
del instance1.temp
print instance1.temp   # [1, 2, 3]  uses the class' temp again
```

Comment: It's a list, not dict. Great answer, though :)

Comment: Ok than why there is a need of `self` in my second scenario to access the temp variable as I understand `self` just represent the current calling object.

Comment: @jamylak: right so self is representing object here. So why I am not able to access the value of temp directly inside the function in 2nd scenario why it has to accessed with self.

Comment: @Noob `temp` without `self` would always refer to a local variable. In python you don't operate automatically on `self` (like you do in java on `this`).

Comment: @mata: thanks for clearing that. I am from java backgroung so I was thinking `self` and `this` behaves in the exact same way.

Comment: no, in fact `self` is always passed explicitly as the first parameter to a method. (even calling it `self` is just a convention, but a very strong one).

Comment: @mata: Can you refer a nice tutorial or book to understand these concepts.

Comment: @Noob - Start with the [official python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html), or hover over the [tag:python] tag and click info for references.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, `MyClass.temp` is always a class variable.  Getting `obj.temp` returns the class variable, until you try to set `obj.temp`, which creates a member variable that masks the class variable.  I hope this helps:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     temp = 5
... 
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> b = MyClass()
>>> a.temp
5
>>> b.temp
5
>>> b.temp = 6
>>> a.temp
5
>>> MyClass.temp = 7
>>> a.temp
7
>>> b.temp
6
>>> a.__dict__
{}
>>> b.__dict__
{'temp': 6}
>>> MyClass.__dict__
{..., 'temp': 7}
```

Edit: As [mata says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862293/382471), calling methods (such as `append()`) on `obj.temp` does not count as "setting" it.

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a class variable. When you access the variable it is searched through the layers of inheritance so since it is not found in the instance itself it checks the class(next layer up)  and finds it there.